# Browser based wallet (NFT)

Tags: wallets, nft

We are seeking for the ideal wallet to offer to our users/customers/sellers. What browser-based wallet is recommended to integrate in a Tesoz nft marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pick a single wallet. You can use a a third party service called Beacon (https://www.walletbeacon.io/) to allow your users to choose which wallet they want to use, with your marketplace. Every user can use a different wallet and your app doesn't need to know or care about any of it.

If you are looking to recommend a wallet to users who might be new to the ecosystem. I work for Kukai, who have just launched Kukai 2.0 web wallet. One of the major features is a revamped NFT display, thats getting a lot of positive feedback. You can check it out here: https://wallet.kukai.app/

Answer (score 1):

Why not Temple Wallet - https://templewallet.com/

I think it is a legit wallet.

Comment: can you please expand on your answer and offer additional color why you think it is a good wallet ? thanks!

Comment: TempleWallet is simple, works in web browser like MetaMask, good for newbies which want to touch Tezos world.